# How to obtain a unique information (maybe serial number or something else) of a scanner with C#, Windows Application?

Tags: c#, windows

I need to store default scanner selections of users.

I don't know if those serial numbers written under scanners are stored in somewhere but I need to get a spesific detail about scanners. Otherwise it can cause conflict.

How can I do that with C#?

Comment: scanner as a peripheral device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I'm not sure if I should answer this or not but because selecting a scanner was an issue to me some time ago I decided to give you a hint...*

This is how you would do it with [WIAAut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663303(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
CommonDialogClass commonDialog = new CommonDialogClass();
Device device = commonDialog.ShowSelectDevice(WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType, true, false);
if (device == null)
    return;

string deviceID = device.DeviceID;
```

EDIT:

one more example how to get the device later:

```
DeviceManager deviceManager = new DeviceManager();
DeviceInfo deviceInfo =
    (from DeviceInfo di in deviceManager.DeviceInfos
     where di.DeviceID == deviceID
     select di).SingleOrDefault();
```